# Trying to serve static JS files Node.js, Err 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io

I am trying to set up a simple node.js server to do some basic Socket.io work but when I try to serve my Static JS files I get this error:

GET https://somewebsitewithfiles.website net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Here is my server and local code:

Server:

```js
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/HTML/index.html');
});
app.use(express.static('Static'))

http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Socket.IO server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
})
```

Local:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="/Static/User.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see I have used the express static file command witch doesnt seem to be working . My file system consists of my project folder and inside that is my Server JS file. There is also folder in there called "Static" that has has my static files and a folder called HTML that has my index.html

any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.use(express.static('Static'))
try putting this line above your '/' route

code:

```
var express = require('express');  
var app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static('Static'))
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/HTML/index.html');
});


http.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Socket.IO server running at http://localhost:${port}/`);
})
```

**Edit:**

```
<script src="/Static/User.js"></script>
```

You dont have to mention the 'static' in the src path.

Correct  way:

```
<script src="/User.js"></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by putting the slash above my route? Please Elaborate

Comment: put this app.use(express.static('Static')) above app.get('/',...)

Comment: I see, will try

Comment: New error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () for the js file.

Comment: <script src="/User.js"></script>
you don't have to specify the 'static' in the SRC

Comment: Oh. Thats strange because the user.js and index.html are in diffrent folders. User.js is in Static and the html is in HTML. will try

Comment: THANK YOU. I didnt realize that when you served the static files they went into the same directory